# How can one end of a cable be full duplex and the other end half duplex?

Tags: networking, router, connection, switch, cable

I know the concepts of full duplex, half duplex, duplex mismatch
1-But I do not understand, how can one side of a cable be "full" and the other side "half"! in other word:(How is ping done successfully?)
2-In terms of what happens inside the cable, I do not understand how the wires on both sides are connected to the devices, one side is "full" and the other side is "half".**(How can a cable provide such a service?isn't it a twisted pair to send and a twisted pair to receive in "full"? So what about "half"?)** or **(What is happening inside cable?)**
To make it clearer, I gave the following scenario:
R1 ping ==> R2 (R1 is auto negotiation which will be half) , switch 2950-1 is full duplex
Ping is done successfully!

[image]

Comment: Regarding question 2, the pinouts and signalling used by twisted-pair Ethernet have been _extensively_ documented, both for the simple 10/100 Mbps Ethernet (search for 100BASE-TX) and the more complex Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T).

Comment: I think you might want to check your assumption that auto-negotiation means half-duplex.

Comment: @mtak: The _lack of_ autonegotiation on one end tends to result in the other end (which still tries to autonegotiate and fails) selecting half-duplex as the safe fallback, no?

Comment: @mtak No, I know the reason for this. Questions about the lack of coordination between the two ends of the cable and the physical description inside the cable.